# AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.sequential' has no attribute 'add'

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, keras-layer

AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.sequential' has no attribute 'add'

I am working on an image classification in this a problem  keras.engine.sequential has no attribute add

Answer (score 0):

Please use from Keras.models import Sequential for image classification. and also if you could more elaborate the problem with your code snippets.